# What was Ramanujan's solution to the House Number Problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, math-history, problem-solving, continued-fractions

[The wikipedia entry on Ramanujan contains the following passage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan#Mathematical_achievements):

> One of his remarkable capabilities was the rapid solution for
> problems. He was sharing a room with P. C. Mahalanobis who had a
> problem,
>
> > Imagine that you are on a street with houses marked $1$
> > through $n$. There is a house in between $(x)$ such that the sum of the
> > house numbers to left of it equals the sum of the house numbers to its
> > right. If $n$ is between $50$ and $500$, what are $n$ and $x$?
>
> This is a
> bivariate problem with multiple solutions. Ramanujan thought about it
> and gave the answer with a twist: He gave a continued fraction. The
> unusual part was that it was the solution to the whole class of
> problems. Mahalanobis was astounded and asked how he did it. "It is
> simple. The minute I heard the problem, I knew that the answer was a
> continued fraction. Which continued fraction, I asked myself. Then the
> answer came to my mind," Ramanujan replied.

What was the continued fraction, and how did it give all solutions to the problem? Most importantly, how could someone derive such a solution? Do similar problems also have continued fractions that describe all solutions?

This seems like an interesting and powerful method, and I would like to learn more about it.

Comment: The problem reduces to a Pell equation whose solutions can be obtained from the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An expansion of Andre's comment into a detailed exposition can be found at http://www.johnderbyshire.com/Opinions/Diaries/Puzzles/2009-06.html. It's also at http://www.angelfire.com/ak/ashoksandhya/winners2.html#PUZZANS4.

Comment: See also http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/miniature/miniature2.pdf an article by John Butcher, where he guesses that Ramanujan was thinking of a (more general type of) continued fraction namely $$3 - \cfrac{1}{6 - \cfrac{1}{6 - \cfrac{1}{6 - \dots}}}$$.

Answer (score 7):

We will use

> **Theorem 1:** If $r\gt0$ is irrational and $\left|\,\frac pq-r\,\right|\le\frac1{2q^2}$ where $(p,q)=1$, then $\frac pq$ is a continued fraction convergent for $r$.

and

> **Theorem 2:** If $\left\{\frac{p_k}{q_k}\right\}$ is the sequence of continued fraction convergents for an irrational $r\gt0$, then $r$ is between $\frac{p_k}{q_k}$ and $\frac{p_{k+1}}{q_{k+1}}$ and $\frac{p_{k+1}}{q_{k+1}}-\frac{p_k}{q_k}=\frac{(-1)^k}{q_{k+1}q_k}$.

---

The problem can be written as
$$
\overbrace{\ \frac{x^2-x}2\ }^{\substack{\text{sum of $1$}\\\text{to $x-1$}}}=\overbrace{\frac{n^2+n}2-\frac{x^2+x}2}^\text{sum of $x+1$ to $n$}\tag1
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
8x^2=(2n+1)^2-1\tag2
$$
From $(2)$, we get $\frac{2n+1}x=\sqrt{8+\frac1{x^2}}$; thus, we want an over-estimate for $\sqrt8$ that has an odd numerator. Furthermore, $(2)$ implies
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{2n+1}x-\sqrt8
&=\sqrt{8+\tfrac1{x^2}}-\sqrt8\\[9pt]
&=\frac{1/x^2}{\sqrt{8+\frac1{x^2}}+\sqrt8}\\
&\le\frac1{2\sqrt8\,x^2}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Theorem 1 and inequality $(3)$ say that $\frac{2n+1}x$ needs to be a continued fraction approximant for $\sqrt8$ to satisfy $(2)$.

The continued fraction for $\sqrt8$ is $(2;1,4,1,4,1,\dots)$. The convergents are
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
k&0&\color{#C00}{1}&2&\color{#C00}{3}&4&\color{#C00}{5}&\dots\\\hline
\frac{p_k}{q_k}&\frac21&\color{#C00}{\frac31}&\frac{14}5&\color{#C00}{\frac{17}6}&\frac{82}{29}&\color{#C00}{\frac{99}{35}}&\dots
\end{array}\tag4
$$
The repeating continued fraction gives the following numerator/denominator recurrence
$$
\begin{align}
a_{2n}&=4a_{2n-1}+a_{2n-2}\tag{5a}\\
a_{2n+1}&=a_{2n}+a_{2n-1}\tag{5b}
\end{align}
$$
Theorem 2 says that the red terms, the ones with odd indices, are over-estimates. Furthermore, the recurrences $\text{(5a)}$ and $\text{(5b)}$ guarantee that the red terms have odd numerators.

Combining $\text{(5a)}$ and $\text{(5b)}$, we get that the recurrence for the odd numbered numerators and denominators is
$$
a_{2n+1}=6a_{2n-1}-a_{2n-3}\tag6
$$
Thus, we can get the solutions from the odd-indexed terms of $(4)$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
k&1&3&5&7&9&\dots\\\hline
\frac{p_k}{q_k}&\frac31&\frac{17}6&\frac{99}{35}&\frac{577}{204}&\frac{3363}{1189}&\dots\\
\frac{n_k}{x_k}&\frac11&\frac86&\frac{49}{35}&\frac{288}{204}&\frac{1681}{1189}&\dots
\end{array}\tag7
$$
The pair that has $50\le n\le500$, is $(x,n)=(204,288)$.

Checking:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{203}k=20706=\sum_{k=205}^{288}k\tag8
$$

Answer (score 3):

See Pi Mu Epsilon Journal Vol. 14 # 6 pp 389-97, 2017.
"House Number Puzzle: Solution Through Bifurcation"

A summary from the above Pi Mu Epsilon publication is given below:

> Continued Fraction of √2 is: 1, 3/2, 7/5, 17/12, 41/29, 99/70, 239/169 ... The above (x/y) also form solutions to the Pell's equation: x ² −2 y ² = ±1. The house numbers are products of x and y (the solutions to the above Pell's equation): 1*1; 3*2; 7*5; 17*12; 41*29 ... and the total number of houses are provided by x*x and 2*y*y alternatively. Total number of houses: 1*1; 2*2*2; 7*7; 2*12*12; 41*41 ...

For details see the actual publication.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to solve the problem by continued fraction, you can easily find by try and error (2x² = n² - n) the following solutions:
x = 0, n = 0, x = 1, n = 1, x = 6, n = 8, x = 35, n = 49. Having found these solutions, we can see the solutions for n form a row. Each new solution for x is six times the last solution minus the solution before the last solution.
6 is 6 x 1 minus 0 and 35 = 6 x 6 minus 1. The same goes for n, but we have to add 2. 8 = 6 x 1 minus 0 plus 2. 49 = 6 x 8 minus 1 plus 2. So we have the conjecture that the next value for x will be 6 times 35 minus 6 is 204. And that the next n will be 6 x 49 minus 8 plus 2 = 288. Filling these numbers in in the equation 2x² = n² - n proofs the conjecture is right. This way we can find the next solution x = 1.189 an n = 1.681. And so on and on.

Comment: This is hard to read.  Please consider typesetting using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).